# TextInput onChange event receives text object not string

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm trying to update redux state from a TextInput `onChange` event that is within a ListView component. In my case I am displaying a list of ratios. I want to parse the edited ratio into its two values. However, the `text` value passed into the `setItem` method is not a string as I expected but it seems to be a Text or TextInput object.

`editItem` is a redux action that performs the edit on the redux state.

How can I get the input string value so that I can pass it to the action?

```
class DataList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Bind the function so we can use it on onPress event
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);

    const { data } = this.props.currentData;
    this.dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    })
  }

  render() {
    // Keep dataSource up to date with redux state
    const { data } = this.props.currentData;
    const dataSource = this.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data.list);

    return (
      <View>
        <ListView
          dataSource={dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) => <View key={`${sectionID}-${rowID}`} style={styles.separator} />}
          style={[styles.list, {height: windowDims.height}]}
          initialListSize={1}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  setItem(index, text) {
    console.log (index + "; [" + text + "]")
    console.log (text) // Prints out what looks like a Text or TextInput object
    var { data } = this.props.currentData;
    var numerator = parseInt (text.substring (0, text.indexOf('/'))) // Fails as it does not find a string
    var denominator = parseInt (text.substring (text.indexOf('/')+1))
    this.props.dispatch(editItem(index, { numerator: numerator, denominator: denominator }));
  }

  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            keyboardType={'numeric'}
            onChange={(text) => this.setItem(rowID, text)}
            value={rowData.numerator + "/" + rowData.denominator}
          />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) documentation it seems to me that you need to use onChangeText event.

Update: using onChangeText will give you an object containing a text property with the changed text string.

Comment: You can use either. `onChangeText` results in the same issue

Comment: Actually that was a good clue! Using onChangeText results in an object containing a `text` property with the changed text string, minimal change to get it out. Thanks! I'll accept your answer if you want to edit it to add that detail...